# Integração com Python e JS

Tags: javascript, python, script

No momento estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que utiliza um código em JS para poder gerar uma foto de uma div e um script em python que envia um email com uma foto em anexo, gostaria de saber se há alguma forma viável de realizar uma integração, onde eu aperto um botão na tela, que chama o primeiro script em JS e depois executa o script em Python. Tentei utilizar o Brython mas não consegui importar as bibliotecas do MIME...

Código em JS:

```
function screenshot(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('photo')).then(function(canvas){
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);

          onRendered:
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            a.download="outweb.png";

            a.click();
        })
      }
```

código em python:

```
import smtplib
import imgkit

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

try:
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port = 587
    acc_addr = 'emailquevaienviar@email.com'
    acc_pwd = 'senha'

    to_addr = 'emailquevaireceber@email.com'
    subject = 'Teste de envio!'
    body = 'Este é um teste de envio de email via Python!'

    #Gera a imagem da tela do html

    #Referenciando o arquivo que está junto com o script
    imgkit.from_file('index.html', 'outweb.jpg')

    # Configura o servidor de envio (SMTP)
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(acc_addr, acc_pwd)

    # Cria o documento com várias partes
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["From"] = acc_addr
    msg["To"] = to_addr
    msg["Subject"] = subject

    # Anexa a imagem
    imgFilename = 'Gauge.jpg' # Repare que é diferente do nome do arquivo local!
    with open('outweb.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        msgImg = MIMEImage(f.read(), name=imgFilename)
    msg.attach(msgImg)

    # Anexa o corpo do texto
    msgText = MIMEText('<b>{}</b><br><img src="cid:{}"><br>'.format(body, imgFilename), 'html')
    msg.attach(msgText)

    # Envia!
    server.sendmail(acc_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print('\nEmail enviado com sucesso!')
except:
    print('\nErro ao enviar email!')
```

Answer (score -4):

no seu caso eu recomendaria construir uma API no backend Python para receber uma requisição javascript já com o conteúdo da imagem em anexo e só depois realizar o envio do e-mail. Recomendo que dê uma olhada no [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) - biblioteca Python para manipular API.

Comment: Olá Heitor, eu tinha decidido em integrar o Flask nessa aplicação, mas me chamou a atenção a utilização de outros recursos, como um envio de emails pelo próprio Javascript.
Pra isso, no momento estou estudando sobre a implementação do SMTPJS.

Comment: Show Kayama !! Peço que pense bem na arquitetura do seu sistema, aconselho que o envio de e-mails fique no backend. Caso deseje fazer em JS, terá que utilizar o Node JS. Abraços